# Remove Method for In-order Iterator for AVL Tree

Tags: java, iterator, avl-tree

I have to implement an in-order iterator for an AVL Tree. To do that, I stored all the nodes (using an in-order traversal) in an ArrayList. I can do the hasNext() and next() methods pretty easily using this ArrayList and a counter variable. But I don't know how to implement the remove() method. If I remove something, there is a chance the underlying AVL tree will self-balance and this will throw the ordering awry...which will mess up the hasNext() and next() methods of the iterator. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private ArrayList <E> recInOrderToArrayList (AVL_Node <E> node, ArrayList<E> inOrderList){

     if (node == null){
         return inOrderList; 
     }
     else{
         recInOrderToArrayList (node.getLeft(), inOrderList);
         inOrderList.add(node.getData());
         recInOrderToArrayList (node.getRight(), inOrderList);
     }

     return inOrderList; 
 }

 public ArrayList <E> inOrderToArrayList (){
     ArrayList<E> inOrderList = new ArrayList <E> ();
     return recInOrderToArrayList (root, inOrderList); 
 }




private class AVL_inOrder_Iterator implements Iterator <E>{

     private AVL_Node <E> current; 
     private int current_num = 0;
     private ArrayList <E> inOrderList_2; 
     private int size; 


     public AVL_inOrder_Iterator (){
         this.current = root; 

         if (root!= null){
             //store all nodes in ArrayList w/ inOrder Traversal
             inOrderList_2 = inOrderToArrayList();  
             size = inOrderList_2.size(); 
         }   
     }

     public boolean hasNext (){
         if (current_num > size) return true; 
         else return false; 
     }

     public E next(){
         if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

         else {
             E data = inOrderList_2.get(current_num); 
             current_num ++; 
             return data; 
         }
     }
```

Comment: Have you run into problems right now? Would be best to show some code so it is easier to see where your problem is coming from.

Comment: I will add in some code for the iterator!

Comment: I don't think the ordering gets "thrown awry" - In-order iteration on an AVL tree is always sorted.  If you remove something you simply jump to the next highest element.  Regardless of how it got rebalanced.  That is kind of the point of AVL (and similar sorted tree) implementations.

Comment: @RayToal 

I don't think I understand that. Say I have a tree whose in-order traversal is A,B,C,D,E,F,G. I put those leters in my Array List. Now if I want to delete D and this causes a rotation, there is a chance the in-order traversal has changed. But my ArrayList will not have changed accordingly, right?

Comment: Rotations, by definition, don't change the inorder traversal?

Comment: @LouisWasserman

Thanks! I guess I had never realized that. For whatever reason, I can't seem to vote on your answer, but I just wanted to let you know it helped me out!